# what prerequisite classes must I have before I take Abstract Algebra and Real Analysis at the undergrad level?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, advice

what prerequisite classes must I have before I take Abstract Algebra and Real Analysis at the undergrad level? Will these prerequisites help me with these two coursea at the graduate level? or do I need new prerequisites at the grad level? Thank You!!

Comment: A good course in Calculus is good for Real analysis. Abstract algebra just needs some "mathematical maturity" and possibly some Linear Algebra (depending on how it is taught)

Comment: You probably don't need much more than an open mind and a willingness to work through definitions and proofs... *Copied from somewhere..

Comment: What does your course catalog say?  Have you talked to or e-mailed any of the people in the math department who teach these courses?

Answer (score 5):

There is so much variation in programs and courses from one school to another that only the most general recommendations are really possible. You really should talk to people in the mathematics department at the university in question. Still, a few generalities are perhaps worth mentioning.

What you chiefly need for both is a certain amount of mathematical maturity. At least in the U.S. most of the mathematics that students typically see up through calculus, and often up through basic linear algebra and differential equations, is primarily computational; the real analysis and abstract algebra courses will be primarily theory-oriented, and the transition from the one to the other doesn’t always come easily. Some mathematics departments recommend a specific course as the transition course from primarily computational to primarily theoretical mathematics; if that’s the case at your school, you should probably follow the recommendation. If not, you might at least consider taking a sophomore-level discrete math course first, if one is offered: these courses typically require a bit more abstract thinking than the usual calculus course while still dealing for the most part with pretty concrete problems.

Depending on what’s on offer at your university, you might consider taking topology or elementary number theory; topology goes well with real analysis, and elementary number theory with abstract algebra. Depending on just how the courses are taught, elementary number theory can give you a bit of a leg up on abstract algebra, or abstract algebra can make some of elementary number theory almost trivial. Similarly, a topology course may build on some of what you learn in a first real analysis course, or it may serve as a foundation for the topological concepts of real analysis by introducing their more general counterparts in a setting that is less cluttered with detail.

Answer (score -1):

I would mainly say that you should have a grasp of former knowledge in the following mathematics topics:

1. Basic Arithmetic
2. Linear and Elementary Algebra and Algebra 1
3. Statistics and Analysis
4. Precalculus and Calculus
5. Number Theory

In abstract algebra, you deal with some Boolean Algebra concepts such as binary operations systems using 0 and 1 and you primarily study algebraic structures such as rings, groups, lattices, fields, modules, and sets.

Comment: Please use the list feature in Markdown in order to improve the appearance of lists. Help on Markdown can be found here: http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-lists